# Cybersource Flex api: How to use the tokenize card request?

Tags: cybersource

So I know that I have to first generate a key with this request `https://apitest.cybersource.com/flex/v1/keys`. And than I know that I have to make a request to `https://flex.cybersource.com/flex/v1/tokens` so I managed to do this, but for some reason I have to use this request's v2 version so I would have to use this `https://flex.cybersource.com/flex/v2/tokens`. I know that it exists, but I cannot find any documentation about it, and It works differently than the v1 version of it.

Does anyone know how use this request?
Or can someone send me a documentation of it?

I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I get the impression that they intentionally don't document it so that you'll use one of their SDKs. For example, this is the one for javascript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cybersource/flex-sdk-web

Comment: Or maybe if you have Flex added to your CyberSource account, you can request the documentation. I never thought of trying that. I actually ended up using flex microforms instead, since the flex token endpoint doesn't seem to allow you to store a security code along with the cc number.